# abstracting iterative object conversions

Tags: java, design-patterns, converters

I have a collection of objects that I wish to convert freely in-between. Let us call them A through F.

The relationship between the objects might look something like this

```
A -- B -- C -- F
     |         |
     D -- E ----
```

What this means is A can be converted to B but not C, if you want to convert A to C then you have to convert it to B first, then to C from there.

I'm having trouble coming up with an extensible and flexible implementation of this that would allow the easy addition of new types and the conversions that go with them. Even after combing through every design pattern I could find I'm no closer to coming up with an answer.

Initially, I had one Converter class that looked something like this

```
public class Converter

public B convA2B(A in){...}
public A convB2A(B in){...}
public C convB2C(B in){...} etc
```

this proved to be unwieldy as I tried to add more types. Next, I tried having multiple converter objects all extending the same abstract class

```
public abstract class Converter

final static int typeA = 0;
final static int typeB = 1;
final static int typeC = 2;
int type;

public abstract A toA(Object in);
public abstract B toB(Object in);
public abstract Object fromA(A in);
public abstract Object fromB(B in);
...

public Object convertTo(int type, Object data)
{
    switch(type){
        case 0: return new A().toA(data)
etc etc
```

Essentially what would happen is each converter would convert the data to the next object type in the path, before passing that data on to the next converter.
ie, if I wanted to convert from A to C, A.toC(x) would call B.toC(A.toB(x)).

this didn't work because each converter type needed to have some basic understanding of the relationship between all the types in order to know when converter to call next, which meant adding new converters became quite difficult in places and could even lead to infinite loops if handled poorly.

What should I do? Many of the design patterns I read about seem to be close to what I'm looking for, like mediator, chain of responsibility, interpreter,  but I'm not certain how to adapt them to do what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is the same thing as your first idea, but it neatly sidesteps the unwieldiness of the combinatorial explosion by treating `Converter`s as objects that can be combined.

Define `interface Converter<A, B>` as a converter from `A` to `B`. This is going to end up the same as `Function<A, B>`, but we are attaching some extra semantics to it, so we may as well not confuse them:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Converter<A, B> {
    B convert(A a);
}
```

Define a bunch of `Converter`s. For each class, *only* define `Converters` for their direct neighbors (`Converter<A, B>`, but no `Converter<A, C>`).

```
Converter<A, B> aToB = a -> { ... };
Converter<B, C> bToC = b -> { ... };
Converter<B, D> bToD = b -> { ... };
// etc.
```

Now, to get from `A` to `D`, we need to combine `Converter`s somehow. This is easily done by adding to `Converter`:

```
@FunctionalInterface
interface Converter<A, B> {
    B convert(A a);
    default <C> Converter<C, B> after(Converter<? super C, ? extends A> pre) {
        return c -> this.convert(pre.convert(c));
    }
    default <C> Converter<A, C> then(Converter<? super B, ? extends C> post) {
        return a -> post.convert(this.convert(c));
    }
}
```

Now, you can write

```
// For a mathematician
Converter<A, C> aToC = bToC.after(aToB);
// If you aren't a mathematician
Converter<A, C> aToC = aToB.then(bToC);
```

You shouldn't store these compositions in a `static` somewhere, because then you'll get a hard-to-manage combinatorial explosion, one for every path in your graph. Instead, the code simply creates them as-needed with `after` and `then`. Adding a new type involves adding new `Converter`s for its immediate neighbors in the graph.

If you don't feel like using `Converter`, you can use `java.util.function.Function`, which is the same thing (but `convert` is `apply`, `after` is `compose`, and `then` is `andThen`). The reason I wrote a new interface is that `Converter` is semantically different from `Function`. A `Converter` is a part of your specific universe of types; a `Function` is a function between any two types. Although they have the same code, they mean different things (you could say that `Converter<A, B> extends Function<A, B>` though).

Comment: functionalinterfaces are a new concept to me, so I'm struggling a bit to completely grasp this answer, although it looks very promising. You say that I shouldn't store aToC for example anywhere, but that it will be generated as needed. How so? What exactly decides the route from A to C, or E?

Comment: The conversion from A to B is defined as `aToB`. The conversion B to C is defined as `bToC`. You can combine these into a conversion A to C as `aToB.then(bToC)`. Whenever you need to convert an `A` into a `C`, you use that. If you want to automatically pick the path, you can build a graph with types at the nodes and `Converter`s in the edges. You find a path through the graph, combine all the `Converter`s, and then run it.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem. This is what I came up with:

A base abstract Model class from which A, B, C... will extend:

```
public abstract class Model {

    protected Set<Class<? extends Model>> targets;

    public abstract                     Set<Class<? extends Model>> targets ();
    public abstract <T extends Model>   T                           convert (Class<T> target);

}
```

The B class for example (since it has the most connections)

```
public class B extends Model {

    public B () {

    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<? extends Model>> targets () {
        if (targets == null) {
            targets = new HashSet<> ();

            targets.add (A.class);
            targets.add (C.class);
            targets.add (D.class);
        }

        return targets;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings ("unchecked")
    @Override
    public <T extends Model> T convert (Class<T> target) {
        if (target == A.class) {
            return (T)toA ();
        } 

        if (target == C.class) {
            return (T)toC ();
        } 

        return (T)toD ();
    }

    private A toA () {
        A a = new A ();
        // your conversion code
        return a;
    }

    private C toC () {
        C c = new C ();
        // your conversion code
        return c;
    }

    private D toD () {
        D d = new D ();
        // your conversion code
        return d;
    }
}
```

And your converter class:

```
public class Converter {

    public Converter () {

    }

    public <S extends Model, T extends Model> T run (S source, Class<T> target) throws Exception {

        if (!source.targets ().contains (target)) {
            throw new Exception ("Inconvertible types.");
        }

        return source.convert (target);
    }
}
```

And finally on your code, what you'll do is:

```
B b = new B ();

Converter converter = new Converter ();

try {
    C c = converter.run (b, C.class);
    F f = converter.run (c, F.class);
    E e = converter.run (f, E.class);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace ();
}
```

Comment: @Taeo, you're welcome to accept the answer that worked for you :)

Comment: this answer is nice and clean, but I probably wasn't clear enough in my problem description. I want the user to be able to convert from any type to any other type with a single method call, and have converters somehow find a path and chain together the conversions to reach the target in the background. I'd rather not throw an error if a direct conversion isn't available.